# Pass frame to another class

Tags: python, opencv

How do pass the img frame from another class?

Example:

I have the process.py

```
import cv2
from camera import Camera
from fire_detection import FireDetection

camera = Camera()
camera.connect()
while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    if frame is not None:
        #Especifico a configuração dos bombeiros
        FireDetection = FireDetection.configBombeiros(frame)
        #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        camera.disconnect()
        cv2.destroyWindow('frame')
```

In this class i call  FireDetection = FireDetection.configBombeiros(frame) and pass the frame as a parameter, but i received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processamento.py", line 11, in <module>
    FireDetection = FireDetection.configBombeiros(frame)
  File "E:\Matheus\MachineLearning\mvc_fogo\novo padrao\fire_detection.py", line 17, in configBombeiros
    mascara = cv2.inRange(rgb, minimo, maximo)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Class fireDetection()

```
import cv2

class FireDetection(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Inicio')

    def configBombeiros(frame):
        minimo = [170, 0, 245]
        maximo = [220, 255, 255]


        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (21, 21), 0)
        #Metodo de detecção de cor (pode ser usado HSV ou RGB) RGB se utiliza o metodo padrão de cor, exemplo: Vermelho 255,0,0
        rgb = frame.copy()

        mascara = cv2.inRange(rgb, minimo, maximo)


        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely to be an issue with the type of `minimo` and `maximo`. The documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) says they need to be arrays or scalers. Hence, try passing in a numpy array or a scaler,

```
minimo = np.array([170, 0, 245])
maximo = np.array([220, 255, 255])
```